# Max amps and voltage CAT5e

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement, amperage, small-gauge-wire

I have CAT 5e running throughout a house.  Trying to use the wiring to connect a CCTV camera.  The camera says it uses 500 mA and needs a 12 V adapter. I do not know if it needs a full 12 V to run. I have an 1 amp 12 V DC adapter to run it.  I was thinking of putting a fuse on the 24 AWG wire to prevent a fire.  It’s running about 200 ft.  What is the max voltage and amps I can safely put through the CAT5e which has strands of 24 ?

Comment: Is this a PoE camera or are you rolling your own setup?

Comment: No, it’s not POE and not an IP camera

Comment: Are you intending on using 4 wires for +12V and 4 wires for GND? Or do you need some of the wires for a signal too?

Comment: I was intending to use 1 pair, to and back for DC and another pair for video signal. So a total of 4 wires.

Comment: If it's not an IP camera, are you sure the signal can be transmitted on twisted pair?

Comment: Passive PoE injectors and extractors with 12 V regulated output over Cat5/6 exists commercially. Get yourself one of those.

Comment: Like this? https://a.co/d/5t3El40 ? But this does not seem to maintain voltage from wire resistance. Does it?

Comment: No. You need a proper one.

Comment: What would that be? Would you be so kind to post equipment that meets spec?

Comment: @Lefty Probably an "802.3af injector" would be the best standard - that's a 48V injected supply. Then a "12V regulated 802.3af splitter" for the same standard.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem will be the ~10 ohms of resistance in the 400 ft round trip cable run which will drop your 12V to 7V at full load. You will need to supply more than 12V to the line - 24V is a convenient voltage - and drop it down to 12V at your camera. 500mA isn't much but in this day and age there's really no excuse not to use a switching converter, especially since it will let you reduce the current in proportion to the line voltage, which in turn reduces the voltage drop at the far end. I would also put a 500mA fuse inline since it's getting close to the (very conservative) rating for 24 AWG. And of course there are modules you can buy that do all this out of the box.

Comment: For 24 gauge wiring, I read that max amps for chassis wiring is 3.5amps, vs max Amps for transmission is 577ma.  What is the difference between the two?  Also can you send me a link to a module so I can see what you are referring to?

Comment: The chassis wiring rating assumes some amount of air circulation around the wires; power transmission is "worst case" and assumes the wire is in the center of a bundle with other current carrying wires and cannot as effectively dissipate heat.

Comment: _"CAT5 is rated for 300V"_ - As far as I'm aware there's nothing in the CAT5 spec that mandates that. I have seen plenty of CAT5 cables rated for 100-150V. Suggesting that CAT5 cables as a category are rated for 300V is dangerous if it's not true. Always check the actual cable in use for its rating.

Comment: @marcelm though I have not seen 150V Ethernet cable (even our 5 mil insulation slim cable is 300V rated), if you've seen it it clearly exists and as you stated only the datasheet is definitive. I will remove that portion of my answer. Also make sure that the cable is plenum rated if you are using it as such.

Answer (score 5):

At 500mA for your camera, the IR drop for that length of run will probably be unacceptable. You will be facing some reliability issues. You could try it (use at least two pairs for your power, one pair for your signal.)

In any event you will need to adapt your video signal to Cat5e. Use a pair of ‘BNC to Cat5’ converters for this. These adapters perform an impedance match, and also decouple your signal from the DC.

If you do run into power problems, consider adding Power-over-Ethernet (PoE). PoE overcomes the IR drop problem by using a higher DC voltage over the wire.

For a single feed, you would use a pair of PoE adapters for each end of your Cat5e: an ‘injector’ at the head end, and an ‘extractor’ output at your camera. 12V is a common output voltage.

Comment: The camera has an rca connector, but the video recorder has a bnc.  What is impedance matching?  Can someone post links to parts I referenced? I have posted some items found above but not sure what I actually need. Want to make sure I do not cause a fire or something

Comment: Single-ended video connectors (including BNC and RCA) are 75 ohms, unbalanced. Cat5e is 100ohms, balanced. The adapter converts one impedance to another with a transformer. It’s a passive device.

Comment: At the camera side use an RCA to BNC adapter.

Comment: @Lefty My suggestion is to use the information in this answer to do the impedance matching for the signal wire pair and then use the remaining 6 wires for the power. No need to leave bonus copper dangling so triple up your +12V and GND lines which will lower the IR drop. Like suggested in the answer, you could give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, why reinvent the wheel here? This is precisely why there are standards for [Power-over-ethernet (PoE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet).

Sticking to the standard approach also means you don't find yourself frying devices if you accidentally plug something in that isn't expecting the cable to be used for power purposes. Standardised PoE injects will by design not damage non-PoE devices plugged in to them.

---

PoE uses a higher drive voltage (typically a nominal 48V) and therefore lower current to overcome the high resistance of the ethernet cables. At the receiver end, you then use a switching regulator (DC/DC) to step this voltage down to a stable level for your device.

For your case, you want 12V 0.5A, or 6W. In which case you can go for the lowest end PoE standard **802.3af**, which provides up to ~13W at the device end even with up to 20Ω of cable resistance (other answers calculate your run is about 10Ω, so you have plenty of margin).

You therefore want some form of "802.3af Power Injector" at one end. These are designed for injecting the 48V supply into an ethernet cable if they detect a proper PoE device at the far end. Then at the camera end, you want a "Regulated 802.3af Power Splitter" device. These provide the proper PoE detection handling, and will regulate the received voltage using a switching regulator to a specified output (12V 1A output splitters definitely exist).

---

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that the camera needs close to 12 volts to work and, with 0.5 amps running down 200 feet of cable, it's my judgement that the volt drop and voltage perturbations seen on the camera power terminals will be highly problematic.

My advice: use a higher-than 20 volt supply at the sending end and, a decent point-of-load buck converter at the camera end.

<sub>CAT5e has a loop resistance of about 0.16 ohms/metre. This translates to about 0.05 Ω per foot. 200 foot means a loop resistance of 10 Ω and, half an amp would drop 5 volts leaving 7 volts at the camera. Do you see the problem that you need to solve.</sub>

Comment: Would this work? https://a.co/d/38rRuyW  It’s 5amps but I assume that is ok as it’s the max.  If I use a 24v and it drops to 16v, should I assume this device makes sure it outputs 12v stable?

Comment: The words on the tin say it should work but, I don't trust any electronic module that doesn't have a data sheet or is made by a company with a unclear quality system.

Comment: What would you recommend? Brand? model?

Comment: Buy from a reputable supplier because they sell goods that have a quality record and can be authenticated. Not Amazon or eBay or bang good or any of the other dodgy sites that sell garage built and garage designed modules.

Comment: Who are the reputable suppliers that sell this stuff? My only resource currently is amazon.

Comment: @Lefty Probably yes. I'll contrast with Andy: while electronic parts sold at electronic parts places do come with full specifications (data sheets) and that's a good filter for the quality of the listing, and Amazon is a shadier marketplace where they don't, they generally do still work for simple applications where you don't actually need to know the data on the sheet, many people use them, and you can too if you get a good deal. I'll also note that $10 isn't a particularly good deal for 500mA as you could find 500mA converters at real electronic part stores (with datasheets) for that price.

Comment: @Lefty Reputable suppliers are the ones who know about the stuff they're selling, basically. Amazon doesn't know - it sells whatever. The top online suppliers I know of are Digi-Key, Mouser, and Element14/Farnell - those are like the Sigma-Aldritch or McMaster-Carr of electronics. Depending on where you live there are probably more local places too, maybe even actual stores. But as stated above, I don't agree that buying simple modules for general use from anywhere that isn't complete sh*t is actually a problem. If it works, it works.